# Finding Left Ideals of $M_2( \mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> I can't figure out how to find all left ideals of the ring $$M_2(\mathbb R)= \left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\quad |\quad a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R} \right\}.$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: what can you say about the rows of the matrix multiplication $AB$, where $B$ is in the ideal and $A$ is arbitrary?